# Deduction rule for c++ auto argument

Tags: c++, auto

For the following function:

```
auto foo(auto A) {
  int a = 9 + A;
  return A;
}
```

What are A being deduced? Does it depend on the caller or it can be deduced to integer because of the integer addition? For example a call `foo(1.5f)` will deduce A to `float`?

Answer (score 1):

> For example a call foo(1.5f) will deduce A to float?

Yes, but the syntax you are using to define your function is a GCC extension.

Consider using:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T A)
{
    int a = 9 + A;
    return A;
}
```

Or if if you want a lambda function:

```
auto foo = [](auto A)
{
    int a = 9 + A;
    return A;
}
```

In both cases, if it's called with an argument of type `float`, then the return type of foo will be deduced to `float`. If you want the return type to to be `int` then you should return `a` or cast `A` to `int`.

When you use `auto` as the return type of a function, the return type will be deduced to the type of the first return expression, and you must return the same type if there's different return paths. For example:

```
if (1 == 1)
    return (float)a;
else
    return (int)b; // Error because the return type has already been deduced to float.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension as far as I know. It will deduce the same as a template parameter. Think of this:

```
template<typename T> // more verbose equivalent of your code
auto foo(T a) {
  int a2 = 9 + a;
  return a;
}

// ...

foo(1.f); // T is float
foo(std::valarray<int>{1, 5, 8}); // T is std::valarray<int>
```

And the return type will be deduced as the type of the expression used in the return statement.